# YUI MenuButton is huge when first displayed

Tags: yui, yui-menu

I have a YUI (2.8.x) MenuButton that is lazily loaded via an AJAX call. I'm not doing anything special to limit the number of items visible at one time. When the items are first loaded, they are all visible, even if the page has to be extended to fit them, but each time you display it after that, the menu is size-constrained to the viewport and you get up/down scroll arrows. Is there a way to force that behavior for the first click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround, I just `hide()` and then `show()` it. That is clearly suboptimal, but at least the user experience is a little better.